# OpenCVとCUDAのインストールについて

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, cuda

### 問題点

現在，OpenCVを用いたGPUプログラミングの環境構築をしようとしています．
しかし，いくつかの問題点がありインストール（厳密にはlib，dllの作成）に失敗してしまいます．何か原因が分かる方いましたらご教授お願い致します．

### 開発環境

- ハードウェア

  - Core i7-4770
  - GeForce GTX 660
- ソフトウェア

  - Windows 10 (Windows SDK already installed)
  - CUDA Toolkit 9.0
  - Visual Studio 2017

### Error Message

Visual Studioで`OpenCV.sln`を開き，`INSTALL`プロジェクトをビルドすると以下のようなメッセージが出てきます．

```
...
2>CMake Error at cuda_compile_generated_gpu_mat.cu.obj.cmake:206 (message):
2>  Error generating
2>  F:/opencv-3.4.0/build/modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/Debug/cuda_compile_generated_gpu_mat.cu.obj
2>
2>
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" はコード 1 を伴って終了しました。
2>プロジェクト "opencv_core.vcxproj" のビルドが終了しました -- 失敗。
...
10>CMake Error at cuda_compile_generated_column_filter.16sc1.cu.obj.cmake:206 (message):
15>CMake does not need to re-run because F:/opencv-3.4.0/build/modules/phase_unwrapping/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
10>  Error generating
10>  F:/opencv-3.4.0/build/modules/cudafilters/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/Debug/cuda_compile_generated_column_filter.16sc1.cu.obj
10>
10>
10>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" はコード 1 を伴って終了しました。
16>Building Custom Rule F:/opencv-3.4.0/opencv_contrib-3.4.0/modules/fuzzy/CMakeLists.txt
10>プロジェクト "opencv_cudafilters.vcxproj" のビルドが終了しました -- 失敗。
...
```

Answer (score 3):

古いCMake（v3.9）を使っていて同じ現象に遭遇したことがあります。質問回答時点で最新のCMake v3.10.2を使うと問題が改善されました。

Comment: （遅ればせながら）回答ありがとうございました。  
CMake v3.10.2で試行しましたがダメでした…  
  
CUDA_ARCH_BINやCUDA_GENERATIONの設定がまずいんでしょうか（今はデフォルトでやってます）？  
CUDAインストール後に忘れがちな環境変数等の設定などorまとめサイトをご存じでしたらご教示ください（英語でも可です）

Comment: まず，問題を切り分けるためにVS2017でCUDAプロジェクトを作成してビルド，実行できることを確認するとよいと思います（そこで失敗するのであればOpenCV以前の問題です）。

Comment: また，↑がうまくいくようであれば，関連しそうな修正がOpenCV 3.4.1で入ったのでこのバージョンを使うと改善するかもしれません．https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/10497

Comment: CUDA v9.1をインストールし直しサンプルをビルドしてみましたが、いくつかエラーが出ました。
（Windows環境での説明で申し訳ないですが）例えばdeviceQueryはビルドできても、asynchAPIは以下のエラーが出ます。
**コマンド ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.1\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=\"sm_30,compute_30\"
..(略).. "C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v9.1\0_Simple\asyncAPI\asyncAPI.cu"" はコード 2 で終了しました。** / 
**#error:  -- unsupported Microsoft Visual Studio version! Only the versions 2012, 2013, 2015 and 2017 are supported!**

1つ目はCUDAで結構有名なエラーですが、根本的な解決方法が分かりません。2つ目なんですが、VSのバージョン落としたほうがいいのでしょうか…？

Answer (score 1):

CUDA9.1は最新のVisualStudio2017ではコンパイルできません。15.4までなので、VisualStudio2017のバージョンを確認しましょう。
15.45のインストーラーはもしかしたらもうダウンロードできないかもしれません。
VisualStudio2015なら対応していますので、14.45のインストーラーが見つけられなかったらあきらめてVisualStudio2015をを使ってください。
コンパイルエラーはヘッダーファイルのコメントにCP932で表示できない文字が入っているのが原因ですので、コメントを削除するなりUNICODEで保存しなおしたり英語環境でコンパイルすれば良いでしょう。

Comment: ほかのところにも似たようなこと書いてありますので参考にしてください。